# Does JAXA have any super heavy lift rockets?

Tags: jaxa

Recently, [JAXA and Toyota announced that they are developing a self driving rover for the late 2020s](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jamiecartereurope/2019/03/12/toyota-reveals-self-driving-moon-car-as-japan-prepares-to-land-astronauts-on-the-moon/#2a681d6b6dc8), do they have the ability now to launch anything that heavy, or are new rockets and launch centers being developed?  Is there any more to their plan about how else they plan to get people to the Moon?

Comment: I thought JAXA was more into building super-_light_ rockets? (Light as in lightweight, not light as in _c_.)

Comment: @Sean Of course JAXA isn't developing FTL rockets. Everyone knows that's [a NASA thing](https://www.iflscience.com/space/nasa-reveals-latest-warp-drive-ship-designs/)! *Mutters about clickbait "science" articles*

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the largest launcher mentioned on JAXA's website is the in-development [H3](http://global.jaxa.jp/projects/rockets/h3/), which is a medium-lift launcher in roughly the same class as Atlas V or Falcon 9; it could land a very small payload on the moon but probably not a crew-carrying rover, let alone the rest of a crewed moon landing-and-return mission.

If JAXA is planning to land a crewed mission in 2029, they will need something in the Saturn V or SLS class, something more than 5 times the size of the H3. The [Saturn V took almost 6 years from NASA's commitment to first flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V#Saturn_development), and aerospace development tends to be more complicated and time-consuming today, so one hopes that JAXA has a super-heavy lift rocket on the drawing boards today.

Comment: JAXA seems to be working towards more international cooperations (with arianespace most notably) for futur launchers; and launching on a non Japanese rocket (SLS, ...) is an option.

Comment: That's certainly a possibility, though the political implications would be... complex.

Comment: Kibo launched on a shuttle :)

Comment: In orbit assembly/refueling technology has moved forward since Apollo. It might be more practical to combine multiple smaller launches.

Comment: Development of the F-1 engine of the first stage of Saturn V took 10 years from 1955 to 1965.

Comment: @Antzi three shuttle flights to carry all the bits up.

Comment: @SteveLinton They'd still need a much heavier launcher than H3; 6+ launches would be impractical for an Earth Orbit Rendezvous mission.